# Updatinging google visualization on the same div when I press link buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I am creating a dashboard for crime data using Google Visualization. 
I have four links that when they are pressed, should update the data weekly, monthly, quarter and annually. Now I have a graph that presents the weekly data, but I want to update the graph in the same div(here is classdiv1) when I press on the "quarter" link for example. I coded my graphs, but I cannot figure out how to update them and map them to my links. Any ideas would be much appreciated. I attach part of my code below. Thanks.

```
<div class="classdiv-1">
    <div class="classmenu1">
        <a href="#"><center>Weekly</center></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="classmenu2">
        <a href="#"><center>Monthly</center></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="classmenu3">
        <a href="#"><center>Quarter</center></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="classmenu4">
        <a href="#"><center>Annually</center></a>
    </div>
</div>

function drawChartW() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Crime', 'Incidence', 'Stock Loss'],
        ['1',  50, 34, 55],
        ['2',  117, 46, 21],
        ['3',  66,  54, 42],
        ['4',  67, 59, 52]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Thread Trends'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('classdiv1'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The other 3 graphs are of the same type and they are named drawChartM(), drawChartQ() and drawChartA().

Comment: do you really name your classes that way?? `:S`

Comment: I am using some dummy data at the moment, so I do not emphasize on code quality and maintenance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to have four different `drawChart`-methods. Consider this :

```html
<div class="classdiv-1">
  <div class="classmenu1"><a href="#" onclick="drawChart('w');return false;"><center>Weekly</center></a></div>
  <br>
  <div class="classmenu2"><a href="#" onclick="drawChart('m');return false;"><center>Monthly</center></a></div>
  <br>
  <div class="classmenu3"><a href="#" onclick="drawChart('q');return false;"><center>Quarter</center></a></div>
  <br>
  <div class="classmenu4"><a href="#" onclick="drawChart('a');return false;"><center>Annually</center></a></div>
</div>
```

You have different arrays for each period (see test arrays in fiddle below)

```js
function drawChart(period) {
  var data;  
  switch (period) {
     case 'm': 
        data=monthly; break;
     case 'q': 
        data=quarter; break;
     case 'a': 
        data=yearly; break;
     default :
        data=weekly; break;
  };      
  var dataSet = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
  var options = {};
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(dataSet, options);
}
```

`onload` weekly will be desplayed, the `default`

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

working fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LtVV3/**